# sed: replace strings having issue due to special character

Tags: bash, sed

Kindly suggest a optimum solution to replace below string in a bash script.

```
input_string= 'cn=xxxxx\, yyyyy (abc-ns),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
to_be_replaced_str= 'cn=aaaa\, bbbbb (abc),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'

sed "s#'${input_str}'#'${replace_str}'#g"
```

But I am not getting any result and it's not changing with desired out.

```
input_string= 'cn=xxxxx\, yyyyy (abc-ns),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
to_be_replaced_str= 'cn=aaaa\, bbbbb (abc),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'

sed "s#'${input_str}'#'${replace_str}'#g" 

input_string= 'cn=xxxxx\, yyyyy (abc-ns),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
to_be_replaced_str= 'cn=aaaa\, bbbbb (abc),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'

sed "s#'${input_str}'#'${replace_str}'#g"
```

blank output.

Comment: The [Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) will give you a good starting point for learning about Bash.

Comment: Obvious problems: you can't put a space after `=` in an assignment, and the variable names don't match. Possible problems: the single-quotes in the `sed` command and/or the escapes in the strings might not be wanted, but we can't tell without knowing what the input and expected output are.

Comment: input_string='cn=xxxxx\, yyyyy (abc-ns),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
to_be_replaced_str='cn=aaaa\, bbbbb (abc),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com' , even this is not working sed "s#'${input_str}'#'${replace_str}'#g"

Comment: @Tkumar What *exactly* are the original contents of the file and the desired replacement contents? Are the single-quotes actually part of the file? What about the backslash? You should edit your question with exact file contents (in code format). Don't put the info in a comment, they don't handle code format as well.

Comment: Hi GD, yes single quotes are the part of the file, what we are doing here we are extracting a LDAP user definition and create replace it with other user connect string  and I have given you the exact content.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your script snippet: you can't put spaces around the `=` in a shell assigmnent, the variable names you assign don't match the ones you use, and the backslashes in the strings aren't right (if they're part of the string to be replaced, they need to be doubled so `sed` treats them as literal backslashes rather than escapes). With these fixed, it appears to work for me. With this script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_string='cn=xxxxx\\, yyyyy (abc-ns),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
to_be_replaced_str='cn=aaaa\\, bbbbb (abc),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'

sed "s#'${input_string}'#'${to_be_replaced_str}'#g" sample.txt
```

And this input file (sample.txt):

```
ldap_user = 'cn=xxxxx\, yyyyy (abc-ns),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
```

It produces this output:

```
ldap_user = 'cn=aaaa\, bbbbb (abc),cn=users,dc=box,dc=com'
```

If the backslashes are not there in the actual file, remove them from both strings. Similarly, if the single-quotes are not there in the actual file, remove them from the `sed` command (but not around the variable assignments, that's part of the shell syntax).

p.s. This question would've been a lot easier and faster to answer if you'd included the actual input file (or relevant section of it) and desired output.